# Function(dot)value [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

How do i create a function with a value after it?

e.g

```
function gotolocation(href) {
    href = href + "?search=stackoverflow";
    window.location = href;
}

gotolocation.href = "https://google.com";
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this syntax?  Why can't you just call this function and pass it a value?

Comment: It could be done using Object or Class [Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) but not exactly in the way you expect it to (from the above provided).

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. No need to alias periods. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can use a setter, but does not make much sense. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

```js
const gotolocation = {
  set href(url) {
    url += "?search=stackoverflow";
    window.location = url;
  }
};

gotolocation.href = "https://google.com";
```

but in such case `gotolocation` would be an Object with a Setter *function* bound to the `href` property, not a function per-se.

---

If your question was: *"How to use this function"*
than the answer is simple: your function accepts one argument, so pass one:

```js
gotolocation("https://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object with function, like class in OOP;

```js
const location = {
   href: "https://facebook.com",
   goto: () => {
      let link = location.href + "?search=stackoverflow";
      window.location = link;
   }
}

location.href = "https://google.com";

location.goto();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a value to a function

`gotolocation("https://google.com");`